# python singleton into multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How can I code to share the same instance of a "singletonic" class among processes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best is to designate one specific process as owning that instance and dedicated to it; any other process requiring access to that instance obtains it by sending messages to the owning process via a Queue (as supplied by the multiprocessing module) or other IPC mechanisms for message passing, and gets answers back via similar mechanisms.

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of processes is to have different address spaces. If you want to share information between processes you must use some means of [interprocess communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can share the instance between the processes, but you can have the instance access shared memory: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes to control it's state if that is really what you want to do.

However, as stated in other answers, it might be easier to achieve what you want with a Queue.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.6 the `multiprocessing` module has a `Value` object used for [sharing state between processes](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).  They have a code sample that should give you an idea of how to share state in this manner, and you can use this approach when writing a singleton class.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use one of the `multiprocessing.manager` shareable data types

```
import multiprocessing as mp
manager = mp.Manager()
shared_list = manager.list()

def worker1(l):
    l.append(1)

def worker2(l):
    l.append(2)

process1 = mp.Process(target=worker1, args=[shared_list])
process2 = mp.Process(target=worker2, args=[shared_list])

process1.start()
process2.start()
process1.join()
process2.join()

print shared_list
```

output would look like:

[1, 2]

There are a [variety of data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) on offer but you'll need the parent process to pass in the shared object to the child objects.