# Shared memory and comunication between programs

Tags: python, synchronization, shared-memory

I read this: [python singleton into multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109870/python-singleton-into-multiprocessing) but I didn't find the solution of my problem. I have to run the same program (not process) many times in one time. Programs work in the same electronic devices. I must synchronized this programs. Only one program can use device in the moment.

Have you got any suggestions how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use lockfiles in the filesystem.

Comment: I hope it will help, but I will work with this problem in the end of project.