# How do I update the global array from the inside of the function?

Tags: python

I want to write a code that return counts is `[1,2,3,4]` while keeping the parallelized `for` loop. I'm trying to update the global array `counts` from the inside of `increment` function, but it never works and returns `[0,0,0,0]`. Is there any way than I can update the `counts` array from the `increment` function while parallel looping `increment` function?

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mpp
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()

num=5

counts=np.zeros((num,1))

def increment(k):
    global counts
    counts[k]=counts[k]+k

pool = mpp.Pool(4)
pool.map(increment,[k for k in range(0,num)])

print(counts)

stop = timeit.default_timer()

print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiprocessing global variable updates not returned to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055303/multiprocessing-global-variable-updates-not-returned-to-parent)

Comment: You should use singleton class with no lock. But it is recommended not to use multiprocessing with these kind of processes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109930/12422518

Answer (score 0):

Just return `counts[k]+k` and set what you want equal to `increment(k)`